# I'm struggling with the exception of CertificateException. How to generate certificate with subject alternative name

Tags: java, ssl, cas

The stack trace is:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:144) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
```

The solution is:`your certificate should include that ip value as a subject alternative name value (of type IPAddress : key=7).`
But, how can I include the ip value as a subject alternative name value when I generate certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using opessl. check this url, you will find what you need.
[opensslSAN](http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/10/openssl-csr-with-alternative-names-one.html).

Take a look to this part: textually:

> "So by using the common syntax for OpenSSL subject written via command line you need to specify all of the above (the OU is optional) and add another section called subjectAltName=.
>   By adding DNS.n (where n is a sequential number) entries under the subjectAltName" field you'll be able to add as many additional "alternate names" as you want, even not related to the main domain.
>   Obviously the first-level parent domain will be covered by most SSL products, unless specified differently.
>   So here's an example to generate a certificate"
>   
>   `openssl req -new -key endpoint.com.key -sha256 -nodes -subj '/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=End Point/OU=Hosting Team/CN=www.endpoint.com/  emailAddress=administrative-not-existent-address@our-awesome-domain.com/
>   subjectAltName=DNS.1=endpoint.com' > www.endpoint.com.csr`

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the info. Even if i just copy-paste the essential parts, would it be ok? let me know in order to edit the answer please. Thanks again

Comment: yes, that would be great. Please check here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer (the section about links)

Comment: Thank you, I've solved this by "-ext san=ip:xxx.xxx.xx.xx".